# How to construct confidence bound for Time Series Prediction?

Tags: time-series, prediction, anomaly-detection

I have some time series data and am using some Deep Learning techniques to get its prediction. Now, I would like to construct confidence bounds for it.

I calculated the residuals, their mean and standard deviation. Then I plotted prediction vs residuals and calculated mean + 3$\sigma$ and mean - 3$\sigma$, and plotted them on my graph. So, I have something like this

[image]

Now, I would like to use a similar technique so that I can have confidence bounds on time series plots.

Comment: Related [10814](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/52738/10814). See confidence interval plot for time series prediction near end of that answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a technique called "Quantile Regression" which allows you to calculate a percentile of your $Y$ variable, the way a quantile regression works is by giving more penalty to the data far to the desired percentile.

[Quantile Regression](https://www.cscu.cornell.edu/news/statnews/stnews70.pdf)

As you used deep learning (I don't know in which software), maybe you could tailor a penalty function which does the same as quantile regression does or maybe the code you are using has it implemented.